# Adding media to GMB location using GMB API giving error

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-my-business-api

I am getting this response when I try to post location image in GMB API.

For media category of ADDITIONAL, LOGO, COVER it save successfully.But when another Category is selected got this response in return. Categories options are following according to documentation.

COVER, 
PROFILE, 
LOGO, 
EXTERIOR, 
INTERIOR, 
PRODUCT, 
AT_WORK, 
FOOD_AND_DRINK, 
MENU, 
COMMON_AREA, 
ROOMS, 
TEAMS, 
ADDITIONAL

Here is my code

```
/**
 * Edit Media for Location
 * @param Acconunt ID | Int
 * @param Request | mixed
 * @return JSON
 */
public function createMedia($id, $request)
{
  $location = $request->get('loc_id');
      if($this->checkAccess($id)){
          if($this->googleClient->getAccessToken()){
              $gmb = new GoogleMyBusiness($this->googleClient);
              try {
                  foreach ($request->get('file_list') as $media) {
                      $data['category'] = $request->get('category');
                      $data['media_format'] = $media['mediaFormat'];
                      $data['source_url'] = $media['sourceUrl'];
                      $media_body = $this->createMediaBodyfromArray($data);
                      $post = $gmb->accounts_locations_media->create($location,$media_body);
                  }
                  return response()->json(['message' => 'Media created Successfully!']);
              } catch (Exception $e) {
                  return response()->json(['message' => 'Media not created Successfully!'],500);
              }
              return;
          }else{
              return response()->json(['message' => 'Couldn`t create Media'],500);
          }
      }
}

/**
 * Make Nedia Object to add Media in Google Location
 * @return Google_Service_MyBusiness_MediaItem
 */
public function createMediaBodyfromArray($data)
{
   $media_body = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_MediaItem;

    // Location Accosiation Object
    $loc_acc = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_LocationAssociation;
    $loc_acc->setCategory($data['category']);

    $media_body->setLocationAssociation($loc_acc);
    $media_body->setMediaFormat($data['media_format']);
    $media_body->setSourceUrl($data['source_url']);
    return $media_body;
}
```

request to POST /v4/accounts/{aid}/locations/{lid}/media

```
returns:
​{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
        "errorDetails": [
          {
            "code": 3,
            "message": "Photo tag \'photos_at_work\' does not apply to this location",
            "value": "photos_at_work"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Hello @DaImTo this error not show for all locations. For some locations it adds for all categories and for some locations it gives error for some categories. Did I miss something? Maybe some media categories are not for all locations?